# OAuthSerivce with James Ferreira Fusion Table Example

Tags: oauth, google-apps-script

I am busy implementing James Ferreira's Fusion Table example from his excellent book, 'Google Script'. However, Google Apps Script has been updated to include shareable libraries since then, and James has also created a shareable fusion tables library at googlescriptexamples.com.

I am able to add the library to my project easily enough, and the autocompletion recognizes the "searchFusion" calls, but when I try to deploy and run, I get "You do not have access to library OAuthService, used by your script, or it has been deleted."

Any ideas on how to get authorized? I have created the required Fusion Table, and included the FUSION_ID as a project property, as required...

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the [OAuthApp library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/google-oauth)?

Comment: Yes I have, thanks. I find it strange that the library is called OAuthApp, but the error is about OAuthService missing

Answer (score 0):

If you change OAuthService in your script (the auto-complete part), into that what +james ferreira has used in his libriary, then it migth just work. I had a similar case where Objapp was changed to ObjApp.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean, could you provide more detail please?

Comment: Have you followed the procedure described in the link: [link](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/google-oauth).

Comment: I created a function:

    function authMe(){
      var options = OAuthApp.getAuth('fusion');
    }

The first time I run this from the script editor, it goes through the whole authorize process, which I choose authorize, grant access. After that, each time I run it, I get the original error message mentioned in this question...

Comment: I see that OAuthApp.getAuth(api) is supposed to return OAuthService - where is the type OAuthService defined?

Comment: Have you selected the fusionTable API in the API console yet?

Comment: I'm sorry for my ignorance! How do I do that??

Comment: It's a bit of the deaf leading the blind.....goto [link](https://code.google.com/apis/console) to activate the fusion tables. In Ch. 7 p. 100, +james is talking about an FUSION_ID. I guess below 25k hits per day you won't need it. Goodluck.

Comment: FUSION_ID specifies which Fusion Table on your Google Drive (you might have more than 1 table) the app should use to store and retrieve the data

Comment: Strangely, if I now add a function Auth() {} and keep it as an empty function, and run it from the editor, I still get the error message, so it seems the error message is being generated from code running somewhere else? I am not sure how I could get an error message by running an empty function?

Comment: (sorry this isn't in a chat, the other participant doesn't have enough reputation yet) Interesting: if I copy and paste the Fusion Source from Google Script Examples into my project, and put it in a 'Fusion Service.gs' file, the web app runs fine, but as soon as I add it by the library key as a shared library, I get the error conditions above...